# Displaying multiple components even after navigation in angular

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to create a sample app like Login and navigating to another modules component. I had created 3 modules names Loginmodule, Adminmodule, Usermodule. In login module component, I designed 2 buttons with different navigations. On first button click I added navigation to User module home component & on second button click navigation to admin module's component.

Even though I'm able to navigate, But still I'm seeing the login component on top of the page.Currently my router-outlet was placed in login component html file. Do I needs to replace to somewhere ?

Loginuser.component.html:

```
<p>login works!</p>
<button [routerLink]="['user','userhomepage']">User</button>
<button  [routerLink]="['admin','adminhomepage']">Admin</button>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

App.routing.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = [
  {path:"admin/adminhomepage", loadChildren:() => import("./admin/admin.module").then(m => m.AdminModule)},
  {path:"user/userhomepage", loadChildren:() => import("./user/user.module").then(m => m.UserModule)},
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  //exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { 
  constructor(){console.log("App-Routing");}
}
```

[image: Folder Structure]

Problem :
[image: Issue-image]

Comment: In app.module.ts file, under bootstrap section I added LoginuserComponent (bootstrap: [LoginuserComponent]) So, I think no need of going for app.component.html right ?

Comment: yes that is right, no need, But you still need a way to replace current route when navigating from

Comment: After replacing the router-outlet to app.component.html, I'm not able to see the  userhomepage view.. Seeing only login page html content.

Comment: Any chance you add this to a StackBlitz app and share the link so I can take a look at it?

Comment: Thanks now it's working. Placed the router-outlet in both app component & login component.